# service depend-on in the docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I have two services `mongodb` and api, they will be started with docker-compose. However, API service needs to wait for `mongodb` is ready, then start.

I know I need to add depend-on, but I don't know how to achieve it.
The question is:

1. How to check if `mongodb` is ready
2. How API depends on `mongodb`.

Could you help me out how to change the following script to make it work?

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    networks: [ "local-fw-net" ]
    hostname: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js
  api:
    networks: [ "local-fw-net" ]
    hostname: api
    image: api:latest
    ports:
      - "3555:3555"
networks:
  local-fw-net:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a `healthcheck` in `mongodb` and reference it in `api`, for example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongosh localhost:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
  api:
    ...
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
```